# disambiguating the idea of a "fixed point" in nonlinear odes versus numerical analysis

Tags: numerical-methods, definition, dynamical-systems, roots, nonlinear-dynamics

I have found that the term "fixed point" gets used in a couple of different math contexts, and that the definitions of the term seem entirely different. I was just wondering whether these two usages are equivalent at some deep level, or just a matter of colloquial usage?

Fixed points in nonlinear ordinary differential equations--a la Strogatz's book *Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos*--refers to a point where the derivative is equal to zero:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x)
$$

where $f(x)$ is a nonlinear function, then there exists a fixed point where:

$$
f(x) = 0
$$

meaning that the first derivative $x'(t) = 0$. This approach makes sense in the sense that the evolution of the system depends on the stability properties at the fixed points.

The second definition of a fixed point comes from numerical analysis, where there is this idea of "fixed point iteration." In this case, a fixed point is defined as:

$$
g(x) = x
$$

This definition seems very different than the definition used in Strogatz. I am not clear on who the numerical methods definition of fixed points is used, but it would not seem to help in solving nonlinear odes?

I was just wondering if there is any connection between these two different definitions of fixed points that I am missing. Or is it just a language thing?

For my own purposes, I have to find the fixed points for a large system of nonlinear odes, and hence I have to use numerical root finding methods to solve for $f(x) = 0$. However, whenever I look at this fixed point topic in papers or computer libraries, I will see references to $0 = g(x) - x$, which is of course the second definition of a fixed point.

Thanks for any explanations.

Comment: Write out the Euler method $x_{n+1}=x_n+hf(x_n)$ to get some similarity. // In my experience, "fixed point" is to be avoided in the ODE context for exactly the reason you give. Use "equilibrium point", "stationary point", "constant solution". // Ha, I knew I answered such a question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3446211/relationship-between-fixed-point-of-differential-equation

Comment: Ahh yes, using Euler's method makes a lot of sense. But the key point is that this term "fixed point" can be ambiguous, especially if people are coming from different mathematical backgrounds. Thanks for the answer @LutzLehmann. I will try and use one of the terms you suggested like equilibrium point or stationary point.